# Unable to edit comments in Tridion UGC

Tags: tridion

I have a problem with a recent install of UGC on a development Tridion environment.  I'm unable to edit comments from the CMS.  I can add comments fine but editing a comment in the GUI results in an error message appearing in the GUI - "Saving comment failed".  No errors are generated in the logs - or at least the logs that I think it should be logging to.  Can anyone give me any pointers?  Does the editing use a different configuration?  My datasource in the webui configuration is below if this is useful:-

```
<DataSource>
<Key>1</Key>
<Match>^(ugc:|oe:|tcm:)+</Match>
<Url>http://new.ugc.service/odata.svc</Url>
<TimeOut>100000</TimeOut>
<Threshold>0</Threshold>
<RatingMinimum>-1</RatingMinimum>
<RatingMaximum>5</RatingMaximum>
<OAuthEnabled>false</OAuthEnabled>
<Locale>en-us</Locale>
<ClientId></ClientId>
<ClientSecret></ClientSecret>
<EventSystemClientId></EventSystemClientId>
<EventSystemClientSecret></EventSystemClientSecret>
<AccessTokenUrl></AccessTokenUrl>
</DataSource>
```

MTIA

John

Comment: Guess I would expect to see an error on the cd_core log for the odata endpoint. Anything there?

Comment: Thanks Nuno.  There are no errors in the cd_core log although I have just noticed that when the UGC web service is restarted then the first time the comments section is opened in the CMS then I get a warning in the log - AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised.  No subsequent errors are reported when attempting to edit comments but I'm assuming the ambient framework will be the issue?  Is the AmbientDataContext not needed for posting comments but it is for editing?

Comment: This AmbientDataContext error is very common, that's probably not it. You say that you are able to add comments. Can you confirm that they are really saved to the UGC database? E.g. by closing the component edit window and opening it again?

Comment: Hi Quirijn, thanks for the reply.  I can confirm that the comments and ratings are saved to the database.  We have this working from both the CMS and front end web site.  All comments and ratings are being stored in the database and we have the UGC web service set up to pull UGC items and display them.  The only thing that we don't have working is the editing of comments.

Comment: Just for further information I've identified that the error I'm getting is - The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.","StackTrace":"   at Tridion.UGC.Model.Services.UGC.PutData.  The json it's trying to send through is data={"d":{"Content":"TEST 1","Status":1,"ItemPublicationId":"68","ItemId":"17793","ItemType":"16","Id":67,"LastModifiedDate":"","CreationDate":"","Score":0,"ModeratedDate":"\/Date(1359645973916)\/","Moderator":"CMSTRIDION%5Cipadmin","User":{"Id":"CMSTRIDIO%5Cipadmin"}}}  I'm thinking it's something to do with security and the Moderator value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  This is now resolved.  The WebDAVModule needed removing from the UGC web service in IIS!  Ok, ok...it's in the docs, but still! ;)  If anybody knows why this would only prevent editing of comments I'd be interested in the answer.  Thanks, John.